# C language:Binary search tree with strings

Tags: c, string, function, tree

I have to create a program for a binary search tree for `strings`, which calculates how many times each word repeats, and it seems like I can't get the program to do as intended, because when printing it out, what should be printed first, are the words/characters smaller than the origin node, followed by the words/characters bigger than the origin node. But what my program does, it just prints it out in the order that I introduced the words/characters, I am still thinking about, how to realise the part of the program that will calculate the number of appearances of each word.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX 15

typedef struct BST
{
    char data[MAX];
    struct BST *left;
    struct BST *right;
} node;

node *create();
void insert(node *,node *);
void preorder(node *);

int main()
{
    char ch;
    node *root=NULL,*temp;

    do
    {
        temp=create();
        if(root==NULL)
        {
            root=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(root,temp);
        }
        printf("\nDo you want to enter more(y/n)?");
        ch=getch();

    }
    while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');

    printf("\nPreorder Traversal: ");
    preorder(root);
    return 0;
}

node *create()
{
    node *temp;
    printf("\nEnter data:");

    temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    fgets(&temp->data,MAX,stdin);

    temp->left=temp->right=NULL;

    return temp;
}

void insert(node *root,node *temp)
{
    if(temp->data<root->data)
    {
        if(root->left!=NULL)
            insert(root->left,temp);
        else
            root->left=temp;
    }

    if(temp->data>root->data)
    {
        if(root->right!=NULL)
            insert(root->right,temp);
        else
            root->right=temp;
    }
}

void preorder(node *root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ",root->data);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

Here's what I came up with, with the help of somebody in the comments, and it works as intended

```
void insert(node *root,node *temp)
{
    int cmp_rezult=strcmp(temp->data,root->data);
    printf("\nCompare:%d ", cmp_rezult);
    if(cmp_rezult<0)
    {
        if(root->left!=NULL)
        insert(root->left,temp);
        else
        root->left=temp;
    }
    if(cmp_rezult>0)
    {
        if(root->right!=NULL)
        insert(root->right,temp);
        else
        root->right=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add: 1) Input 2) Expected output 3) Actual output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `insert` you do:

```
temp->data<root->data
```

but that's not how you compare strings in C.

To compare strings use `strcmp`

Further it seems that `insert` miss a code block for handling "equal".

So something like:

```
int cmp_result = strcmp(temp, data<root->data);
if (cmp_result < 0)
{
    // Handle less than
}
else if (cmp_result > 0)
{
    // Handle greater than
}
else  // i.e. cmp_result == 0
{
    // Handle equal
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your idea worked for me, now I'm thinking on how to count the number of appearances

Comment: @vlad To count the number of appearances walk the whole tree and use `strcmp(..., ...) == 0`. Anyway... I think you shall ask another question for that part.

Comment: Already solved it, thank you for you help